# Can anybody help me with this output , because i dont understand it , its 30 . and im a beginner in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, compilation, output

When I compile the output is 30 . I thought it would be 2 beacause z is smaller than 0 so z = z + 3 , (-1 + 3 = 2):(. I dont get it

```
    int z = -1;

    if(z < 0)
        z += 3;
    else if(z == 2)
        z += 5;
    if(z < 5)
        z *= 15;
    System.out.println("z is  = " + z);
```

Comment: You probably missed an else with if in `if(z < 5)
        z *= 15;` ; for your desired output it should be written as `else if(z < 5)
        z *= 15;`

Comment: Yes, -1 + 3 = 2.  *And* 2 * 15 = 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z = -1;

if(z < 0) //TRUE
    z += 3; //which means (z += 3) = 2
else if(z == 2) //Wont trigger
    z += 5;
if(z < 5) //TRUE
    z *= 15; //which means (z *= 15) ==  (z = 2 * 15) == 30 
System.out.println("z is  = " + z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 if statements that will evaluate to true, the third one does not have an else, so it will happen in addition to the first one since both are true